# How can I configure my wireless to be ad-hoc command-line?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, command-line, ad-hoc-network

In any version of Windows, how can I put my wireless network card in ad-hoc mode through the command prompt?

I want to do this because I want to hide this from the user (ie. I don't want them to have to do by themselves) I'd rather do this using an API or native windows function, but since I found no static approach in any version of Windows, I figured that the CLI is the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
netsh wlan del filter permission=denyall networktype=adhoc
```

removes any filtering for ad-hoc networks.

You can then use

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="SSID" name="Profile" interface="Interface"
```

to connect to a network, where you need to fill in the quotation marks.

The syntax and whether parameters are optional are outlined in [this TechNet document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: This will connect to an already existing network? Can it also be used to create/initialize a new ad-hoc network?

Comment: @Unknown: I don't know of another way. Although you could try to figure out with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) what registry values are accessed to create such a profile and then replicate it with the `reg` command or by producing a `.reg` file and importing it.

Answer (score 0):

To create an adhoc wifi:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<your desired network name> key=<your_desired_password>
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

To stop:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

To get status:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```