# Is it possible to set up a new manual wifi connection from the command line?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, windows-10, ad-hoc-network

I'm trying to work out a solution to set up ad-hock wifi connections in Windows 8.1 based on the suggestions in [a post on Micsrosoft's answers site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/windows-81-ad-hoc-not-showing/5d75d887-ff59-425e-a480-9f80ada63627). Is there any way to do the first few steps:

- go to "Network and Sharing Center"
- click "Set up a new connection or network"
- double click "Manually connect to a wireless network"
- enter the SSID of the ad-hoc network (as shown by "netsh wlan show networks") into the "Network name" field
- configure security settings accordingly
- uncheck "Start this connection automatically" (important)

...without using the windows dialogs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure my wireless to be ad-hoc command-line?](http://superuser.com/questions/352497/how-can-i-configure-my-wireless-to-be-ad-hoc-command-line)

Comment: Does that work for Windows 8.1?

Comment: I don't have 8.1 to test, but it should do.